# Joomla _JEXEC like functionality

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to make some form of a CMS for learning purposes. Now I want to find out how to automatically include a bunch of classes into certain files. I want to write a single line of code that would include all the classes I want it to.

```
<?php include(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])."/lib/php/session.inc.php");

Essentials::getDOCTYPE();
Essentials::getHeader();
```

This is the top of my index file looks like. How can I automatically have that session file included? From what I am able to understand know, that _JEXEC in Joomla defines a custom Joomla session, and then immediately after that usage, there is a $this->baseURL() used, which means there is a class that was somehow used. However, there is no include("myclass.php");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The _JEXEC in Joomla files doesn't do anything as clever as you imagine. It is simply a constant that is defined within the main script's entry point (index.php). Its existence is then tested in subsequent files, as a security precaution to prevent files being accessed directly.

If _JEXEC isn't defined you didn't come in through index.php - if you requested index.php directly, or were silently redirected (rewrittend) to index.php via mod_rewrite, then _JEXEC is defined, if not you must have accessed the other file directly and the script exits with a 'direct access is not allowed' type of message.

I believe the functionality you are talking about can be found with a search based on the words 'php autoload' whereby you can build a function that will look in specific folders for files with names matching patterns you define which include the name of the class you try to instantiate but which hasn't been loaded already.

Comment: That _autoload function seemed to be interesting, I did come across it, I will look further into it. Many thanks for the help.